# How to split a 2d-list based on a condition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have a 2d list, which is an accumulation of multiple (unknown amount) tables.

```
Table |  Value | Name
 "1"  | "0.1"  | "part_1"
 "1"  | "0.11" | "part_1"
 "2"  | "2.0"  | "e_1"
 ...
 "139" | "20.0"  | "kf_1"
```

Now I want to split this list into another structure (list?) where I can access the different tables directly. Like:

```
tables[0].[0].[1] = "0.1"
tables[1].[0].[2] = "e_1"
```

In total, this concludes > 50 mio data rows, therefore RAM efficiency is important.

Comment: I suggest turning the list into Pandas dataframe. Applying differing filtering conditions is pretty easy there.

Comment: installing additional packages is possible, however not optimal, since it will be executed on different pcs without internet access

Comment: Do you want to be able to load the entire 50 million rows into memory? How many times are you planning to access this data?

Comment: try installing numpy, It's built already for that.

Comment: I am currently able to load them into RAM ( around 16 gb). And I don't plan to access it often, it is for data analysis and hopefully will only be run one per dataset

Comment: numpy is not really practical, since I get this as a list with string entries and I can not change the format

Comment: If your list is indeed 16 gb, then it's by no means practical to load all at once. I suggest 1)splitting the file with some logic suitable to you. For instance based on first column: 'table_1.csv' 'table_2.csv'  2) Implementing database like sqlite. (Externa package, I know)